# What is a good time for generating plotly plots in R?

Tags: r, plotly

I am using shiny dashboard, and based on user selection, I am plotting around 60-100 plots; The part of the code can be found below; Now what I realize is that generating the plots is somewhat slow, i.e. for 60 plots I need around 5 seconds and for 100 plots around 8 seconds; Now I am of course wondering if this is expected or if there is some possibilities to bring that number down;

For reference: Each plot has only one time series, which usually has 100-120 time stamps with the respective values;

```
    output$time_series_plots <- renderUI({
    req(shared_data(), input$header_select, dic())
    header_selected <- input$header_select
    
    # Convert timestamps to year-quarter format
    timestamps <- as.yearqtr(rownames(shared_data()), format = "%YQ%q")
    
    # Create a list to store plots
    plots <- lapply(dic()[[header_selected]], function(header) {
      numeric_indices <- which(grepl("^\\d+\\.?\\d*$", shared_data()[[header]]))
      box(width = 2, height = 130,
          plot_ly(shared_data(), x = timestamps[numeric_indices], y = ~as.numeric(.data[[header]][numeric_indices]), type = "bar", height = 115,
                  hovertemplate = paste("<b><i>", strsplit(header, ".", fixed = TRUE)[[1]][6], "</i></b> <br><b><i>(",rownames(shared_data())[numeric_indices], ", %{y:.3f}</i></b><extra></extra>")
          ) %>%
            layout(
              title = "",
              margin = list(l = 0, r = 0, t = 0, b = 0),
              xaxis = list(title = list(text = NULL)),
              yaxis = list(title = list(text = NULL))
            ) %>% config(displayModeBar = FALSE)
      )
    })
    
    # Return the list of plots
    do.call(tagList, plots)
  })
```

Comment: can you pre-process the plotly plots meaning, make them beforehand and then just call them based on user inputs, instead of making each plot based on the user input

Comment: I suppose I could but then I'd have potentially 10,000 plots to compute initially which also seems not like a great idea

Comment: But I just would like to understand of this time to generate is normal or if there are some possibilities to speed up the process

Comment: Some thoughts: (1) are you using crosstalk (judging from `shared_data()`), and do you actually need it (to update other widgets by interacting with your plots)? If not, unidirectional interactivity (widget -> plot) might save *a lot* of calculation. (2) For an array of plots, native facetting features might gain quite some performance compared to "manually" creating an array of plots which you then pick from.

Comment: What would you recommend here? shared_data is defined by shared_data(read.csv(files[1], sep = ",", row.names = 1, header = TRUE))

Comment: Re: what is a good time for generating plotly plots in R? The best time is to generate a plotly plot was 20 years ago, the second best time is today ;)